# Angular 5(Material Table): set Mat-row hidden

Tags: angular, angular-material

is there any way to set mat-row hidden? 
In other words, I'd like to set visibility of mat-row hidden or shown. 
I tried use *ngIF which doesn't work . 
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can you show the line which *ngIf doesn't work? and your .ts file?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `[hidden]` on the `mat-row` with your condition like so:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: cols;"
  [hidden]="row?.shouldHide === true">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mat-table` & `mat-row`, like me, You can use style/class and `ngClass` to achieve this as follows:

**In your css:**

```
.hideMe{
    display: none;
}
```

**In html:**

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns;" [ngClass]="{'hideMe' : row.visible === false}"></mat-row>
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass